# ElementTree XML parsing and urllib2.urlopen

Tags: python, xml, urllib2, elementtree, celementtree

I'm opening a URL using:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(url, data, timeout=_TIMEOUT)
```

and using `response.read()`, it gives the following output:

```
<XMLlookup licenseid="X4X6X42" reason="OK" status="1" />
```

but when I want to parse it using ElementTree, like so:

```
print response.read()
t = ET.parse(response)
r = t.getroot()
print r.attrib.get('status')
```

gives me the following error message:

```
File "<string>", line 62, in parse
File "<string>", line 38, in parse
cElementTree.ParseError: no element found: line 1, column 0
```

but when I remove the line `response.read()`, the code works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only read once a response, because it is a file object like (in fact a addinfourl). Subsequent calls to `read`  will return an empty string since you have always read the whole text.

So either you do not call `read` before using `ET.parse(response)`, or you store the result in a string and use it for ET :

```
txt = response.read()
# do what you want with txt (without changing it)
t = ET.fromstring(txt)
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation! so, i have to store the result to a variable that can hold the string. what if the string is long-ish?

Answer (score 4):

You need to use:

```
t = ET.fromstring(response.read())
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of

```
response.read()
t = ET.parse(response)
r = t.getroot()
```

try

```
resp = response.read()
t = ET.fromstring(resp)
r = t.getroot()
```

or

```
t = ET.fromstring(response.read())
r = t.getroot()
```

Also, you should note that not all HTML is parsable as XML. If your request returns XHTML then you will be fine, but otherwise you will get a very similar error to what you are seeing.

Comment: the output of response.read() is text -- the code above doesn't work.

Comment: I am querying a CGI script that outputs only XML so I know it's not going to produce HTML.